# Deleting row in worksheet

Tags: python, openpyxl

I'm trying to delete a whole row from a worksheet with an index. I do this because i'm trying to do the 3sigma clipping method. Here is my code:

```
import openpyxl
from statistics import mean, stdev

wb=openpyxl.load_workbook('try1.xlsx')

sheet=wb.get_sheet_by_name('Blad1')

v = []
for i in range(1,555):
  v.append(sheet['T'][i].value)

m = mean(v)
s = 3* stdev(v)
# clipping in the list BUT i dont know how to delete a row from a worksheet
for i in range(0,len(v)-1):
#if the value is more then 3 sigma (=s) away from the mean, i want to delete the whole row 
# of information
  if v[i] >= m+ s or v[i] <= m-s:
    # tryin to delete row 'Ai':'Zi'
    sheet.delete(sheet[['A'][i]:['Z'][i]])
```

Comment: Be aware that deleting rows will adjust the remaining rows' positions. To get around this, you can iterate in reverse: `for i in reversed(range(0,len(v)-1)):`. It's also easier to delete the whole row than what you have: `sheet.delete_rows(i,1)` where the 1 indicates that you'd like to delete just 1 row.

Comment: See https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/editing_worksheets.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To delete a row, use this: `sheet.delete_rows(index, length)`.

Basically, index is a **number** which will represent the start of the row that will be deleted. Then, length is also a number which represents the amount of columns that will be deleted from index. For example, `sheet.delete_rows(1, 26)` will delete all the rows, from A to Z.

If you wanted to empty a cell, you can do `wb['A1'] = ""`.

You can also use `move` to shift the cells, which will overwrite any cells. To do this, try this:

```py
sheet.move_range("A1:Z1", rows=-1, cols=2)
```

This will move the cells in the range A1:Z1 up one row, and right two columns. You can change the values of `rows` and `cols` to whatever you need.